# How to include translations for my software?

Tags: c++, locale, translation

I develop C++ software and I would like to offer translations. For this, I had something in my mind like having all text messages in a Messages.cpp and from there reading all strings from the proper language file with the help of a key assigned to each string.

Example:

Messages.cpp

```
std::string test = get_file_entry("de-DE.txt", "key-that-identifies-a-string");
```

de-DE.txt

```
key-that-identifies-a-string: This is a text message that I want to access in my software.
```

**How are translations implemented? Is it done like my approach?**

How do professionals do it like the language settings in video games? May it have something to do with locales?

PS: I do not know more about locales as that they are a set of rules for cultural specific traits (language, number, time, ...). Do not assume that I know much about them since I never worked with something like that in software.

Comment: You should focus on one question a time when you post a question here. Besides that, it is highly option/usecase based. e.g. `Can I select the proper language file in my example according to what the OS locales are? How do professionals do it like the language settings in video games?` that depends. An application like Photoshop is translated in many languages, but most prefer to use it in English instead of the native language, just because all help resources refer to the English naming. You'll have to determine that based on the target user group.

Comment: @t.niese I removed some question. Thanks for the advice. Is it done like this that the software uses the translation file according to the OS locale, by default, and it is switched to other translation files via the software. Like "Options > Language > ..."?

Comment: You can take a look at [Boost.Locale: Messages Formatting (Translation)](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/locale/doc/html/messages_formatting.html), and the other parts of that library. That's only one example of how it can be done. Whether to use a key for translation or the actual text, is also again opinion-based, I prefer the actual text, over a key, because on the one hand it would just display the text in the standard language if the translation is missing, and you directly see what the text is in the application.

Comment: I think that is what I need. If you want to post an answer I will mark it as a solution.

Comment: `Is it done like this that the software uses the translation file according to the OS locale, by default, and it is switched to other translation files via the software. Like "Options > Language > ..."?` there is no general way of doing it. The recommended way would be to do it according to the user expectation on how to change the language, base on the application type and the system they are using. e.g. on macOS, the system preference allows to change the language of a particular application (if it supports changing it that way).

Comment: `I think that is what I need. If you want to post an answer I will mark it as a solution.` library suggestions are off-topic. `boost.locale` is only one library that does this. There is also QT, GNUText, and others, and which one to choose depends on the use-case.